# Is there a difference when class contains empty destrcutor or not

Tags: c++, destructor

Is there a difference between this class::

```
class Osoba{
public:
char* imie;
int wiek;

Osoba(char* imie, int wiek){
    this->imie = imie;
    this->wiek = wiek;
}
};
```

without destructor `~Osoba(){delete imie;}` or with it? Is it correct in both cases?

Comment: If you use dynamic memory allocation for `imie` then writing destructor is good choice to explicitly deallocate memory for out of scope objects, you don't have to take care to `delete imie`, it can be called in destructor, read [when destructor are useful?](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr380.htm)

Comment: This depends. Does `Osobo` own the pointer passed in as `imie`. If it does not own the resource it should _not_ delete it. If it *does* own it then you want to clean it up in the destructor.

Comment: With the destructor, and without deleting the copy constructor, it would be outright incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an important difference.

You're getting `char* imie` from constructor (implies that you didn't `new` that), so you shouldn't `delete` that. Then don't use `delete *imie;` unless you know what are you doing.

The class/object which `new` the pointer is responsible to `delete` it, organize your code in this way.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that in the first case, nothing special happens when an `Osoba`'s life comes to an end. In the second case, you call delete on `imie`, which may or may not be the right thing to do.

What is correct depends on whether `Osoba` is supposed to own the object pointer ad by `imie` or not. If it does not, then you do not need a user defined destructor. If it does, then you need the destructor, plus an assignment operator and a copy constructor, or you need to disable both. The reason for this is that if you do not treat assignment and copying with case, you can end up with many instances pointing to the same object. All of these instances will attempt to delete the same object. See the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).

Answer (score 1):

No, don't delete `imie` in `Osoba` because `Osoba` doesn't know how `imie` was created.

In general, freeing memory is the responsibility of whoever allocated it.  In your case, whoever calls the constructor `Osoba(char* imie, int wiek)` has to create `imie` first.  This might be done with new, or malloc, or strdup, or any other thing that allocates memory.  It may even be something that isn't allocated from the heap.

The point is that `Osoba` does not know anything about `imie`, so *probably* it should not delete it.  Whoever allocated `imie` should delete it.

In fact, probably `Osoba` should be *copying* the string, i.e.

```
this->imie = strdup(imie)
```

in which case you should `free(imie)` in the destructor.  The reason it should probably copy the string is because the caller might have done something like this:

```
Osoba* SomeFunction()
{
    char X[100];
    sprintf(X, "I will be gone when SomeFunction returns");
    return new Osoba(X, 0);
}
```

In this case X will be gone when SomeFunction returns, and Osoba will have a pointer to random memory.

But to answer your question, no, don't delete `imie` in `Osoba` because `Osoba` doesn't know how `imie` was created, unless you decide to copy it, in which case you should free the copy in the destructor.